# Emulator error: user data image is used by another emulator

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error when I try running my program in the emulator:

emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

Deleted the following folders: 
C:\Users\%UserName%.android\avd\AVD2.1.avd\cache.img.lock C:\Users\%UserName%.android\avd\AVD2.1.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock